# Python Finding and Printing Values from Dictionary Selectively

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have written the following code for getting an output of the various districts located in the given city and their respective postal codes:

```
zipcode = {"Trap City":{"C District": 100, "D District": 103, 
           "E District": 104, "S District": 105}, 
           "Zap City":{"R District": 200, "D District": 201},
           "Los City": {"X District": 207, "Y District": 208}}

def list_zip(city):
    print(zipcode.get(city))

for (area,code) in zipcode["Trap City"].items():
    print(area, code)
```

Output:

```
C District 100
D District 103
E District 104
S District 105
```

How do I modify my code to include the ability to receive input from the user (District Name) and output the City in which it is located and it's postal code?

Also how I could input a postal code and get the respective district(s)?

Thanks in advance, a beginner in python.

Comment: I would suggest looking into `sqlite3` module, in-memory database and storing your data there. That way you can do queries like you want relatively effortlessly.

Answer (score 1):

To get input you can use:

```
district=input('Enter your district: ')
```

To get the City in which it is located and it's postal code:
you only need to iterate through the dictionary:

```
for city in zipcode:
    if district in city:
        print(city,zipcode[city][district])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a couple of extra dictionaries via dictionary comprehensions. This has a one-off cost, but thereafter requires only O(1) complexity lookup.

Note, however, this solution isn't dynamic / linked. Changes to your original data will not be automatically reflected in your dependent dictionaries. For this, you should investigate using a database.

```
d_district = {k2: (k1, v2) for k1, v1 in zipcode.items() for k2, v2 in v1.items()}

print(d_district)

{'C District': ('Trap City', 100),
 'D District': ('Zap City', 201),
 'E District': ('Trap City', 104),
 'R District': ('Zap City', 200),
 'S District': ('Trap City', 105),
 'X District': ('Los City', 207),
 'Y District': ('Los City', 208)}

d_code = {v2: k2 for k1, v1 in zipcode.items() for k2, v2 in v1.items()}

print(d_code)

{100: 'C District',
 103: 'D District',
 104: 'E District',
 105: 'S District',
 200: 'R District',
 201: 'D District',
 207: 'X District',
 208: 'Y District'}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python3 then for input you can use this:

```
district=input('Enter your district: ')
```

and if you are using python2 then for input you can use this:

```
district=raw_input('Enter your district: ')
```

To get the City in which it is located and it's postal code: you only need to iterate and apply condition on the dictionary:

```
for city in zipcode:
    if district in city:
        print(city,zipcode[city][district])
```